# Collection is not set in release build

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5

Platform: .NET 4.5, EF6

Original code:

```
model.ContentGroups = new List<ContentGroup>();
model.ContentGroups.Add(new ContentGroup());
```

Working code:

```
model.ContentGroups.Clear()
model.ContentGroups = new List<ContentGroup>();
model.ContentGroups.Add(new ContentGroup());
```

ContentGroups definition:

```
private ICollection<ContentGroup> _contentGroups;    
public virtual ICollection<ContentGroup> ContentGroups
    {
        get { return _contentGroups ?? (_contentGroups = new List<ContentGroup>()); }
        set { _contentGroups = value; }
    }
```

If model.ContentGroups already contains one item, the original code resulted two items in the collection unless deliberately make call to collection Clear()

It only occurs when compiling code in release mode, but not in debug build.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the code related to your `DbContext` and how you are actually using this I can't be certain but I think it is because setting the property to a new list sort of conflicts with entity framework.  I am guessing the issue is related to lazy loading and the way entity framework knows when to do something with the database.  Even though you have set it to a new `List`, EF still goes out to the database and re-fills the list when you enumerate it.  Setting to a new `List` doesn't tell EF to do anything database wise.

If you want to clear the list then all you need is the `.Clear()` call, there is no need to ever set it to a new list. The `Clear()` will instruct EF to update the database when you `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext`.